# Is it save to install CPU that requires high TDP on motherboard that don't support it?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a CPU that uses AM3 sockets.

I replaced that CPU with better ones

https://www.tokopedia.com/snapshot.pl?dtl_id=109255353&order_id=74839874

AMD phenom II

Basically it's my Mom's old computer.

I got a warning that TDP is above 95 degree.

I bought expensive CPU fan and put it anyway.

Well, it works. Should I worry?

Comment: You will definitely stress the electrical systems.  There are low end and high end motherboards, low end board like biostar and pcchips won't handle it for long.  High end boards like asus,asrock, msi, gigabit will fair better as they use higher quality parts.

Answer (score 2):

It's higher heat and electrical draw than the motherboard is rated for.  It may fail faster than it would if operating under the TDP it was rated for.  If this was a recently-produced motherboard, running a too-hot part might void the warranty.  AM3 is an older socket design from 2008, so your motherboard probably wouldn't be covered by warranty anymore.